# Excel unable to copy paste across two workbooks

Tags: excel, copy, paste

I'm trying to copy some data from one excel workbook to another but I am unable to. I can getting some useless message like "unable to copy data"

When I copy into a new sheet in the same workbook then the copying works. What am I doing wrong? It would be very helpful to get this fixed.

Here are screenshots of what I am trying to do:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have restarted my computer twice but that doesn't seem to have changed the problem. I have tried copying entire worksheets or just a cell and I get the same error.

This one time, somehow, "keep source formatting" option showed up while pasting but when I tried to paste, I got this message: "Microsoft is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action" . I only have google Chrome, Adobe, and Paint running on my computer right now.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try not selecting a column in destination workbook before pasting. Just place the cursor in a single cell.

Comment: I tried pasting a single cell to a single cell and I was able to do it when I picked the option "keep source formatting". Same thing for an entire column. But when I tried it for the entire sheet, I ran into an infinite loop of "OLE action" error messages.

Comment: This helped me just now, thanks! Pretty bad UX though.

Answer (score 1):

Could be config corruption, try this:

> Right click on a sheet tab and select "View Code"
>   From the "View" menu select "Immediate Window" if it's not already displayed.
>   Paste the following into the "Immediate Window" and press enter: **Commandbars("Cell").Reset**
>   Of course, deleting the per-user configuration in Excel will delete the user's customizations.

From: http://www.whitemiceconsulting.com/msexcelgreycutnpaste201508